# What colour is the ball?

Tags: annoying-challenge

This is a question from the Annoying Challenge or as it has been newly christened, the Challenge For Losers. I've tried black, grey, hexadecimal code etc.
Anybody know the answer, happy to have a spoiler since I've tried this for 6 months now...

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160871/what-color-is-the-ball

Comment: Yeah but they never gave an answer